# CircularList in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, list, generics, nodes, circular-list

I have been working on an *AS3* project for some while and I think that I've hit a wall. My project requires a series of elements to be arranged in a *Circular List*, so I copied myself in a `Circular List` I had done before in C#.

Problem is, that one was heavily dependant on the usage of *Generics*. Now I don't have those.

Here are the codes. The `T` variable type represents the generics that I wish existed.

Node.as:

```
package
{
    public class Node
    {
        var nodeContent:T;
        var nextNode:Node;

        function Node(nodeElement:T)
        {
            this.nodeContent = nodeElement;
        }
    }
}
```

CircularList.as:

```
package 
{
    public class CircularList
    {
        var head:Node;
        var tail:Node;
        var listLength:int;

        function CircularList()
        {
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
            this.listLength = 0;
        }

        function Add(addition:T)
        {
            adding:Node = new Node(addition);

            if(this.head == null)
            {
                this.head = adding;
                this.tail = adding;
                head.nextNode = tail;
                tail.nextNode = head;
            }
            else
            {
                tail.nextNode = adding;
                tail = adding;
                tail.nextNode = head;
            }
            listLength++;
        }

        function Find(requested:T):Node
        {
            var finder:Node = null;
            var searching = head;
            var i:int;
            while(i <= listLength)
            {
                if(searching.nodeContent == requested)
                {
                    finder = searching;
                }
                searching = searchig.nextNode;
                i++;
            }
            return finder;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this thing work without the generics?

EDIT: The real problem with this is that I want the *NodeContent* in the Node class to be an object. I want to make a list of people sitting on a circular table, basically, but I would like to have a code that I can reuse, rather than something specifically made for this problem

Comment: There's nothing equivalent to c# generics in ActionScript from my quick read-up on generics. However, if you replace T with *, you should be ok (at least as far as the provided code goes anyway). * is the shorthand for "any class type"

Comment: Are you looking to pass a class type into Node or an instantiated object?

Comment: I want the NodeContent to be an object. That's the problem... I think that otherwise it would work with the *(It's what I tried before asking, but yeah, need to get an object there)

Comment: Have you tried replacing Node with * also? eg: var head:*;

Comment: Other option is to use an Interface. Is it practical to define one for the classes that can be nodes?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems like your best option here would be to use an interface.

Instead of using a type have all classes T implement an interface like `INode`. In this interface you can define all the functionality that your type T requires and implement it as needed in each of your implementing classes. This way you can change your function signatures to take type `INode` instead of `Class` or `*` and have a common set of methods that these functions can act upon.

```
function Add(addition:INode){
  //add logic on INode
}



function Find(requested:INode):Node{
   //find logic on INode
}
```

edit: a bit of info about interfaces,

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-to-interfaces/

say we have two Classes, A, B and each of these classes have a similar method, `doTrace`, that needs to be implemented differently. We can define an interface, implement it in both of these classes and pass that type into any method looking to call `doTrace`

Start with the interface called ITraceable,

```
public interface ITraceable{
   function doTrace():void //all methods defined in interfaces are seen as public
}
```

Now our two Classes, A and B

```
public class A implements ITraceable { //implementing our interface, when we do this we need to define all methods in ITraceable

     public function doTrace():void{
          trace("I am A");
     }

}
```

Do a similar thing for B

```
 public class B implements ITraceable {

     public function doTrace():void{
         trace("I am B");
     }

 }
```

Now in some outside class we want to use this

```
 public function letsTrace():void{
      doTheTrace(new A()) //I am A
      doTheTrace(new B()) //I am B

 }

 public function doTheTrace(object:ITraceable):void { //now we can pass both A and B into this function
     object.doTrace(); //since ITraceable requires all objects that implement it have this method we can guarantee it will be here
 }
```

Hope this helps you through your application

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the usage of interfaces, really, but I will make a quick investigation, try to implement it and we'll see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: @Anthony I expanded my answer to include some info about Interfaces, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I will let you know after I implement it, but at the very least I will surely learn a lot from these examples.

Comment: While your input was really helpful for understanding interfaces, I decided that it wouldn't do it for me and created a circular list specific for the class I was working on. While I originally wanted to make an all-purpose CircularList class, it seems impossible without generics. Thanks, though!